# SpecFlow: Having different implementations for steps with the same name

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I'm currently using SpecFlow to create some user acceptance tests. After I've generated the steps, I've noticed that the generator would create a single step for every step in different scenarios which look the same.

The problem is, because each scenario I'm trying to portray is different, even though they may use the same method calls, I would still like to tweak the environment using mocks (Moq). This is rather difficult given all scenario steps which look the same point to the same method (step) in the generated code.

Would someone be able to explain how I should go about this or if my approach is wrong?

Comment: It could suggest that your naming is vague/over-general. If the steps should be executed in different ways, why have they ended up with the same name?

Comment: Hi Damien, it is just the scenario which is different. The system should still follow the same execution path. Because the mocks have been setup differently each scenario should yield different results. I hear what you're saying though, so I'll have a look if I can't introduce parameters as per the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: It would help to see two distinct scenarios with different wiring requirements that have same named steps, and the implementations you'd like for each.

Then we can comment on whether there are changes you can make or features you can leverage.

Answer (score 0):

You could parameterize the Specflow steps. You might have a step like:

```
Given 'Bob' logs in
```

The generated step might can switch on the parameter to perform you different scenarios. e.g.

```
    [Given(@"'(.*)' logs in")]
    public static void GivenUserLogsIn(string user)
    {
        if (string.Equals("Bob")
            DoBobScenario();
        else if (string.Equals("Joe")
            DoJoeScenario();
    }
```

This isn't exactly the same step name, but the parameter is going let you distinguish between the scenarios you are interested in testing.